# Mapbox studio labeling - prioritize label placement by feature size

Tags: css, label, mapbox

I'm totally new to mapbox studio and encounter some problems with the labels. I have a polygon layer and created another point layer just for the labels of my polygons (being the centroids of those polygons). The problem is that there are some areas with many labels and I would like to chose the label that is displayed saying that the label of the point that falls inside the largest polygon should be displayed first. Is there any way to do that in Mapbox studio directly or should I create a ranking field in ArcGIS or any other GIS software before?

Thanks a lot for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MapBox Studio places labels based on the order of the features in the data.  So depending on how you store your data, you will have to do some pre-processing.

If you can store your data in a PostGIS database, it's very easy to do things like this on the fly.  Simply bring it into MapBox Studio with a query somewhere along the lines of:

```
SELECT name, geom
FROM <table>
ORDER BY ST_Area(geom) DESC
```

*or*, because you are trying to get points from a polygon layer:

```
SELECT name, ST_PointOnSurface(geom)as geom
FROM <table>
ORDER BY ST_Area(geom) DESC
```

If you store your data in as a shapefile, you will need to edit the shapefile directly (can't be done on the fly).  Should be easy to do w/ Arc/qGIS.  I know it's possible w/ `ogr2ogr` as well:

```
ogr2ogr -sql \
    'SELECT * \
    FROM <table> \
    ORDER BY ST_Area(geom) DESC'
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. As I was using shapefile I edited them directly.